# Changing The Dock's Appearance From 3D to 2D?

Tags: macos, terminal, dock

Sometimes the glossy finish to the Dock 3D's appearance annoys me, and I want something less bedazzling on the eyes.

Is there a simple terminal command I can use to convert it from a 3D glossy to a 2D plain dock in appearance ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, **but only in OS X 10.8 or earlier**.

You can use the the following Terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean YES && killall -HUP Dock
```

---

To go back to 3D, run the following command (replace `YES` with `NO`):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean NO && killall -HUP Dock
```

Comment: I'm assuming by your first statement, it is not compatible with OS X 10.9 Mavericks (which I would assume only beta testers and developers have anyway).

Comment: @Simon Yes, that is correct.

Comment: If I want to go back from 2D to 3D ?

Comment: @Simon Replace `YES` with `NO` (see edit to answer).

Comment: Excellent, much appreciated.

Comment: Interesting read regarding 2D Terminal Command in OSX Mavericks http://www.tekrevue.com/2013/10/10/popular-2d-dock-terminal-command-wont-work-os-x-mavericks/

Answer (score 3):

The following is a script you can save as whatever you want. I call it `DockChange.sh`. Make sure it has the `.sh` extension on the end.

It needs to be `chmod +x` before you run it; so using the name above I would need to type `chmod +x DockChange.sh` into terminal, then to run it I only need to type `./DockChange.sh` and it will do it's magic.

```
#!/bin/bash
dock2d3d=$(defaults read com.apple.dock | grep "no-glass")
if [ $dock2d3d == "\"no=glass\" = 0;" ]
then
  defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean YES && killall Dock
else
  defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean NO && killall Dock
fi
```

This script will automate the process for you.